# count of common records between two dataframes in python

Tags: python, dataframe

How to get common count of records two dataframes

```html
matched_rcd = pd.merge(onprem_records,athena_rcd, indicator=False,how ='inner')
```

I'm able to get the all the matched records , but not sure on how to get the counts of matched records.

Comment: You need to show a snippet of data: what columns are in each record, and do you only want to merge on index, or on common column(s)? The answer will differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matched_rcd = pd.merge(onprem_records, athena_rcd) #to merge and get the same records only (intersection)
print(len(matched_rcd)) #to count it
```

ref for intersection: https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf